# Shortest hamiltonian path for different dimension points

Tags: np, approximation, hamiltonian-path

The shortest Hamiltonian path (solution) for a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^k$ (in Euclidean space) changes subject to $k$.

For example if for $k=1$, the shortest Hamiltonian path will be the sorted set of points, which can be achieved in $O(n\log n)$.

My question is what happens when $k$ increases - does the solution become more and more complex or is it the same for all values of $k$ larger than $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a variant of Euclidean TSP in which you are looking for a path instead of a cycle. You can (essentially) reduce your problem to the usual Euclidean TSP by adding a point at infinity.

Here is a quick summary of what is known about Euclidean TSP, paraphrasing a survey of Czumaj from the Encylopedia of Algorithms:

1. For every fixed $k$, there is a randomized [PTAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme) due to [Arora](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.23.6765&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [Mitchell](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1283385). The running time has been improved by [Rao and Smith](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6f47/54bd43551db03978b8c44a5b383bb2fe645b.pdf), and by [Bartal and Gottlieb](https://cs.nyu.edu/~adi/sparse.pdf) (in the real RAM model).
2. [Trevisan](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.6336&rep=rep1&type=pdf) showed that there is no PTAS when $k = \log n$ (unless P=NP).
3. Euclidean TSP with an unbounded number of dimensions is known to be NP-hard. The same isn't known for fixed $k$!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "The same isn't known for fixed k"? Does this mean that it may or may not be NP-hard?

Comment: That’s right. We simply don’t know.